# Terminology: "Modelling" a category via a faithful embedding

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $F \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ be a faithful functor between two $k$-linear categories with $k$ a field. For some reason the first category is difficult to compute in, but the second is “easy” (homomorphisms end up being matrices). This means that in order to “model” a hom space $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y)$, I calculate the objects $F(X)$ and $F(Y)$, and then record a finite list of matrices in $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(F(X), F(Y))$ which form a basis of the original hom-space. By doing this for all pairs of objects I’m interested in, I can do all the calculations I need for the part of $\mathcal{C}$ I’m interested in.

What I’m looking for is terminology for what I’m doing: so far I am calling this a “model” of the category $\mathcal{C}$ inside $\mathcal{D}$, but I don’t know if this is correct, or if there are better options (or better yet, this is already called by a specific name).